# training real value neural network using backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

i'm trying to train a neural network for  a real valued output  , i simply give the net interpolated set of points (which looks like square oscillations) however the back propagation always doesn't give me a good fit to the inputs  , i tried to add more features which are higher values of the input and normalised the output as well , but it doesn't seem to help .the network is 3 layers 1 input 1hidden 1 output and one output node 
how can i troubleshoot this problem ?
i also used this cost function is it correct ?

```
for k = 1:m

  C= C+(y(k)-a2(k))^2;
end
```

my code :

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
input_layer_size  = 4;
hidden_layer_size = 60;
num_labels = 1;
load('Xs');
load('Y-s');
theta1=randInitializeWeights(4, 60);
theta2=randInitializeWeights(60, 1);
plot (xq,vq)
hold on 
xq=polyFeatures(xq,4);
param=[theta1(:) ;theta2(:)];

[J ,Grad]= nnCostFunction(param,input_layer_size ,hidden_layer_size,num_labels,xq,vq,0);

       options = optimset('MaxIter', 50);
  costFunction = @(p) nnCostFunction(p, ...
                               input_layer_size, ...
                               hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, xq, vq, 10);


  [nn_params, cost] = fmincg(costFunction, param, options);

Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
             hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size +   1))):end), ...
             num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

         l=xq(:,1);
         out =predictTest(Theta1,Theta2,xq);

          accuracy=mean(double(out == vq)) * 100
         plot (l,out,'yellow');

         hold off



    function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
        input_layer_size, ...
        hidden_layer_size, ...
        num_labels, ...
        X, y, lambda)

    y(841:901)=0;
    y=y/2.2;

    Theta1 = reshape( (nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size+1 ))), ...
        hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size +1 ));

    Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1+(hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size +1))):end), ...
        num_labels, (hidden_layer_size +1 ));

    m = size(X, 1);
    J = 0;
    Theta1_grad = zeros(size(Theta1));
    Theta2_grad = zeros(size(Theta2));


    X= [ones(m,1) X];

    z1=X*Theta1';
    a1 = sigmoid(z1);
    a1= [ones(size(a1,1),1) a1];
    z2=a1*Theta2';
    a2= sigmoid(z2);


    for k = 1:m

        J= J+(y(k)-a2(k))^2;

    end
    J= J/m;
    Theta1(:,1)=zeros(1,size(Theta1,1));
    Theta2(:,1)=zeros(1,size(Theta2,1));
    s1=sum (sum (Theta1.^2));
    s2=sum (sum (Theta2.^2));

    s3= lambda *(s2 +s1 );
    s3=s3/(2*m);
    J=J+s3;

    D2=zeros(size(Theta2));
    D1=zeros(size(Theta1));
    for i= 1:m

        delta3=a2(i)-y(i);
        v=[0 sigmoidGradient(z1(i,:))];
        delta2=(Theta2'*delta3').*v';



        D2=D2+delta3'*a1(i,:) ;
        D1=D1+delta2(2:end)*X(i,:);


    end


    Theta1_grad = D1./m + (lambda/m)*[zeros(size(Theta1,1), 1) Theta1(:, 2:end)];
    Theta2_grad = D2./m + (lambda/m)*[zeros(size(Theta2,1), 1) Theta2(:, 2:end)];

    grad = [Theta1_grad(:) ; Theta2_grad(:)];


    end



    function W = randInitializeWeights(L_in, L_out)


    epsilon_init = 0.5;
    W = rand(L_out, 1 + L_in)*2*epsilon_init - epsilon_init;

    end
```

inputs are 1:9 interpolated 0.01 increments   and the targets are numbers between 0:2.2  like a square pulses

[linear interpolation of data vs predicted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIbLA.png)

[updated after increasing epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4BPq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give more information about the topology of the network and some example input and output data. Please also include the whole algorithm along with the weights initialisation.

Comment: thank you , i've updated  the content

Comment: Can you add a little table of expected output data for each input you give?

Comment: And I'll need to see what the actual output is. A graph is best if you can.

Comment: i added the graph for prediction  and the interpolation of the targets

Comment: When training, how many iterations are you giving backprop before you verify it? In other words: how many times does the network see 9 on the input and 2.2 on the output?

Comment: if you mean the iteration for optimising the gradients , they are  50 iterations

Comment: Is that all? What is your learning rate? I'd expect the # of iterations to be in the 1000s.

Comment: oh yeah i tried to modify the cost function and increasing the number of iterations , it helped alot , Thanks  but not accurate Tho , i tried different learning rates , have a look on the updated output

Comment: OK, that's much better. That looks like your neural network is now working. Of each training class, how many patterns (examples) do you have?

Comment: 901 interpolated points , it's 1 class (continuous output )

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much further, I can't understand how your code is implemented. I can't see network topology and how your time series is encoded.

Generally speaking, the higher the frequency (vertical edges), the more neurons you need. The more neurons you have, the more training examples you need. Keep increasing both to increase accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Note that red line is never zero (*lowest around 0.4*) which signifies that **trained weights** never brings network output to zero (*i mean weight needs to be negative enough and biases either are totally missing or not negative in some cells*)

1. Scale your signal from [-1 to 1] and use both weights and biases to train network to see impact. both weights and biases will be required.
2. Simple neural-network as used here are not fit for time series prediction like square waves. Use prediction models like [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/neural-network-time-series-prediction-and-modeling.html) for time series

Comment: when i use the simple fitting app in matlab it produces a good fitting output

Comment: Simple fitting is non-neural and could be using tricks i've shared here. Both points are important when fitting `real-valued time signals`